# angular directive - Why does not update variable in directive?

Tags: scope, directive

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope){
    $scope.processResultCodeList = [{key:"PRCO00",value:"All"}
                        , {key:"PRCO04",value:"Confirm"}
                        , {key:"PRCO06",value:"Return"}
                        , {key:"PRCO09",value:"Request"}];
    $scope.tempList = ["PRCO06","PRCO04"];
})
.directive('checkModel', function($compile){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            checkModel:"=",
            checkData:"="
        },
        link: function postLink(scope,elem, attrs){
           elem.on('change',function(event){
               console.log(event.target.checked);
               if(event.target.checked){
                if(scope.checkModel.some(elem=>elem!=scope.checkData)){
                    scope.checkModel.push(scope.checkData);
                }
            }else{
                scope.checkModel = scope.checkModel.filter(elem=> elem!=scope.checkData);
            }
            scope.$apply();
            $compile(elem.contents())(scope);
          });
            scope.$watch('checkModel', function(newData, oldData){
            scope.checkModel = newData;
            if(scope.checkModel.some(elem=>elem!=scope.checkData)){
                attrs.$set('checked','');
            }
            if(scope.checkModel.some(elem=>elem==scope.checkData)){
                attrs.$set('checked','checked');
            }
          },true); 

    }
};
```

})

I create check box by using object list composed with key and map. The complete check box is binding array variable, add and remove the key to variable when check or uncheck. Strangely value can insert to variable, however, why didn't remove the value?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rainyseason/bgrpm2ap/19/)

p.s) Sorry, but i'm not good at English. so if you see wrong words, please tell me. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try splicing the array

```
 if(event.target.checked){
          if(scope.checkModel.some(elem=>elem!=scope.checkData)){
                scope.checkModel.push(scope.checkData);
            }
        }else{
          scope.checkModel.splice(scope.checkModel.indexOf(scope.checkData),1)
        }
```

Working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bgrpm2ap/20/

Comment: Thank you! :) But What the problem this case?  Perhaps, Can't I Initialize in isolate scope?